# search for specific repeats (mnr) of length 6 or more in a string using python regular expression

Tags: python, regex, bioinformatics

I have a tab delimited csv file contains 3 comma-separated fields: number, sequence and status. Each line represents a different sequence.

an example of the input file which is called sequences.txt:

```
1 tgctccatatcagtgcagatcgcgcgatacattcctcagtaggaaaaaagttcagagatgataatcgtccgtccgggatttcagatgaaagaggctggaagtcaaggctttagcgggtaggaggttaatgatttt no 
2 tatactatttagttctgcagtgagccttcatacaaagggatgtggagttgtcatatggggggctctgtatccggagttcggttttgcttgagactcaaatcggggttttcgtacat no 
3 ccggctagtgagaggcttaagacatccagatatctcgaatagtaatagcagtcgaaaccgaaattaaaccccaatcactaatggcattcacataatgaatagtgcttactcgacctaagggcgaatt no 
4 ttaattgatttttgtgcaaaaattgatattagagtattacccccgtattgctatgcgcctttctaattgactgattacgtgagacgcgcgggtttggagttcactgggcagacgcgagctacatttgccaggtacgact yes
```

I want to write a program to scan each sequence and check for monomeric nucleotide repeats (mnr) of 6 or more(upper or lower case doesnt matter I'm looking for both). If I find a sequence that matches that criteria, I should then print the entire row into a new output file (with all 3 fields).

Definition: monomeric nucleotides are: repeats of A,T,C,G(it is not case sensitive)

mnr repeats in a row would be something like this: AAAAaaAAgtc or gtAAAAAAAAAAc or aaaaaaAAA or aaaaaaaaaa or ccccccccccc or CCCCCcccCCC or...

I tried this regular expressions but does not work:

```
import csv
import re
with open('sequences.txt','r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")
    for line in reader:
        seq=re.findall(r'[Aa]{6, }',reader)
        if line.__contains__(seq):
            print(line)

with open('seqoutput.txt','w') as f:
    for line in list1:
        f.write(line)
```

expected output:

```
1 tgctccatatcagtgcagatcgcgcgatacattcctcagtaggaaaaaagttcagagatgataatcgtccgtccgggatttcagatgaaagaggctggaagtcaaggctttagcgggtaggaggttaatgatttt no 
2 tatactatttagttctgcagtgagccttcatacaaagggatgtggagttgtcatatggggggctctgtatccggagttcggttttgcttgagactcaaatcggggttttcgtacat no
```

current output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "sequence.py", line 6, in <module>
    seq=re.findall(r'[Aa]{6, }',reader)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 181, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: `for line in reader` is not string. It's a list. Your regex is fine.

Comment: The regex is fine for `a` - you need to scan for the other 3 remaining neucleotides using a similar regex

Comment: And you are mistaking `reader` and the actual line string.

Comment: @knh190 thanks, so what should I put instead of reader in for line

Comment: Why is your output much shorter than the original sequence string?

Comment: sorry I just edited that

Comment: @NazaninShambayati Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the sequence with at least 6 repeating characters you could use a capturing group and a back reference.

```
[atcg]*([atcg])\1{5}[atcg]*
```

That will match:

- `[atcg]*` Match any of the listed in the character class 0+ times
- `([atcg])\1{5}` Capture in group 1 matching any of the listed and repeat the backreference to group 1 5 times
- `[atcg]*` Match any of the listed in the character class 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LSfiMU/1)

You could use the csv reader and choose a comma as a delimiter (as you state that that is the delimiter, note that there are no comma's in the example data)

If it is a tab you could use `'\t'` as the delimiter

If the `sequence` part matches, write the line to a new file using the same delimiter.

Your code might look like:

```
import re
import csv

seqout = open('seqoutput.txt', 'a')
with open('sequences.txt','r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        match = re.match(r'[atcg]*([atcg])\1{5}[atcg]*', row[1])
        if match:
            seqout.write(','.join(row) + "\n")
seqout.close()
```

Comment: I did not get this part?could you please elaborate more: (','.join(row) + "\n")

Comment: @NazaninShambayati You have 3 columns and row[1] is the second column containing the `sequence`. `row` is a list of 3 columns and if you want to write that as a line to the file you have to assemble the string from the items using the comma as a delimiter `(','.join(row) + "\n")`

Comment: I am at work thats why Im replying late, I deleted my first comment... cause I guess I made a mistake in the answer...it gave me output but I have to compare it.. I will get back to you again casue I also have questions from regex..thanks a tons..

Comment: ya actually it did worked...you dont know how much you helped me..honestly I did not understand the regex part:( which section do I need to study to get it or if it is possible can you explain to me what you did? Many many thanks:)

Comment: @NazaninShambayati You are welcome, glad to help! There is an explanation of the regex in the answer but what happens is that there are 4 possible characters to match `[atcg]*` which might be present before the repeated chars. So that is why you use an `*` to repeat 0+ times. To get the repeating characters you first have to capture one of those chars in a group using parenthesis `([atcg])` and check if you can repeat what is captured 5 times. To get a reference to what is captured you use `\1` and repeat 5 times using `\1{5}`. Then match the characters which might follow using `[atcg]*`

Comment: wow such a nice explanation ... I will read more about it as well cause my knowledge about regex is not that much and im a beginner...And does it also work for capital letters? cause i wanted capital letters too...

Comment: In that case you could use `re.IGNORECASE` in this line `match = re.match(r'[atcg]*([atcg])\1{5}[atcg]*', row[1], re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: and juts the last thing to ask. you put {5}. I wanted the repeats of 6 or more, shouldn't be {6} instead? thanks so much

Comment: The first one is in the capturing group, the backreference `\1` is the second and you repeat that 5 times so that would be 6 in total. If the requirement is to match the line if it contains 6 or more, then containing 6 also works. Matching 6 or more would be using  `{5,}`

Answer (score 0):

Your `csv.reader` is yielding a list per iteration, but you need a string per line. Try using simple file open or

```
reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=" ") # tab split
for row in reader:
    sequence = row[1]
    seq=re.findall(r'[Aa]{6, }', sequence) # not reader
```

Your regex can be extended for other alphabets:

```
re.findall(r'[Aa|Gg|Cc|Tt]{6,}', sequence)
```

Comment: it did not work..:(and what should I print at the end? I want to print the whole rows containing the matches..

Comment: @NazaninShambayati what do you mean by "did not work"? I need to know the exception and line number.

Comment: @NazaninShambayati what's the pattern for your output? How is the head and tail appended? I just see the repeating sequence pattern but cannot find to rule the output.